# Error in Silverlight Design view

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have working Silverlight project, however I am not able to edit the design view without it crashing Visual Studio 2010.

I have reinstalled Silverlight Tools 4, and recreated the xaml page from scratch. Google search has not been very helpful, and the link referenced does not tell much in the way of diagnostic info.

Here is the trace info;

`System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
[Async_ExceptionOccurred]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60129.0&File=System.dll&Key=Async_ExceptionOccurred
   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   at Demo1.DataService.GetCustomersCompletedEventArgs.get_Result() in C:\Users\b173242\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Demo1\Demo1\Service References\DataService\Reference.cs:line 120
   at Demo1.LocationDataCollection.GetCustomersCompleted(Object sender, GetCustomersCompletedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\b173242\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Demo1\Demo1\LocationDataCollection.cs:line 67
   at Demo1.DataService.DataServiceClient.OnGetCustomersCompleted(Object state) in C:\Users\b173242\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Demo1\Demo1\Service References\DataService\Reference.cs:line 218
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

System.UnauthorizedAccessException
[InvalidCrossThreadAccess]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60129.0&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=InvalidCrossThreadAccess
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at Demo1.DataService.DataServiceClient.DataServiceClientChannel.EndGetCustomers(IAsyncResult result) in C:\Users\b173242\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Demo1\Demo1\Service References\DataService\Reference.cs:line 323
   at Demo1.DataService.DataServiceClient.Demo1.DataService.DataService.EndGetCustomers(IAsyncResult result) in C:\Users\b173242\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Demo1\Demo1\Service References\DataService\Reference.cs:line 202
   at Demo1.DataService.DataServiceClient.OnEndGetCustomers(IAsyncResult result) in C:\Users\b173242\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Demo1\Demo1\Service References\DataService\Reference.cs:line 210
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)`

Thanks,

Comment: My Visual Studio 2010 crashes every time the designer window opens as well, but I haven't captured the stack to see if it is the same error. I'm stuck in Win XP, so I assumed that was the problem. A useful hint is to right click on a xaml file in the solution explorer, click open with, chose xml (Text) edit and click set as default. Then you'll always open in code view. It works faster and you can at least edit the XAML by hand.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell but it looks like your XAML is using a ViewModelLocator to get a ViewModel that calls a DataService which is crashing.